# 4 Ender Dragons on Outer Islands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I killed the Ender dragon for probably about 4-5th time and entered one of the old portals to the outer islands. As soon as I entered I go attacked by 4 Ender Dragons at the portal !? On an outer island.

What and how causes this ? After some time they flew away into the distance and glitched at max-render-distance.

Should I be careful from now on as I enter other outer islands?[image: 4 Ender Dragons]

Comment: Is this on singleplayer or multiplayer?

Comment: single player, but even single games are connected to a server and are backed up i guess

Comment: Single player is connected to a server... that you're hosting.  I was just wondering if there was any sort of external interference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a duplication glitch in the game. The ender dragon is not allowed to teleport through the end gateways, but still attempts it.

Basically the dragon flies through the end gateway, causing it to teleport to the outer Island. Then the game realises that the dragon is not allowed to teleport the dragon and returns it to the main Island. It's the last bit where it goes wrong. The dragon gets duplicated and is both on the main Island and on the outer islands.
The dragon has a state in which it travels to the exit portal on the main Island. That's why the dragon travels of into the distance.

I can't make much more of it. Just be carefull when you enter any gateways.

Comment: I figured he was trying to get to the center island but wow. So If I follow them can I force them to get to the main island :D That's gonna be one hell of a fight to try take down 4 dragons at once :D

Comment: @DenislavKaragiozov good luck with that!

Comment: What happens if you kill the duplicates far away from the main island?  Do they drop a dragon egg + portal on the main island, where they are, or not spawn them in?

Comment: @phflack A dragon doesn't drop anything except xp if you haven't altered the loot tables. The exit portal is probably already activated because he defeated the dragon on the main Island. so... Probably nothing happens.

Comment: Killing it would be impossible since it only stays above you for 10 seconds or so and than flies to the main island. If you do manage to kill it somehow I would guess it doesnt drop an egg since only the first one does, and the portal would duplicate the portal on the main island, or it fails to create one since it is away from the active chunks. Even worse it might destroy the current one and if that happends, well we wouldnt want that :D

Comment: Interesting thought: Does killing the ender dragon far way load the 0 0 area to activate the portal or does it fail?

Comment: I think what actually happens is that the ender dragon successfully teleports through the gateway, which then puts the dragon into unloaded chunks, causing the game to lose track of it. Then, the game realizes that the ender dragon should be alive but doesn't appear to exist, so summons another one.